# Can this be solve only by loops?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, printf

Since I am kind of a beginner to programming, I try to programm as much as possible. I saw a illustration on how an integer array saves its bytes. I tried to make this illustration in c, just for the learning and I wondered if there is a better way than i did it.

The code below works on its own and if there is a more efficient way, it still should have the same output.

I know that my code would be very challenging if the array would have 100 integers.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int lange = 3;
    int c[lange];
    c[0] = 3;
    c[1] = 1;
    c[2] = 2;


    for (int i = 0; i < lange*4; i++) {
        printf("| ");
        if (i == 0) {
            printf("%d", c[0]);
        }
        else if (i==4) {
            printf("%d", c[1]);
        }
        else if (i==8){
            printf("%d",c[2]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @EugeneSh. is it though? :d To me this looks like the "for-case paradigm"...

Comment: Can you please explain your requirement in a little bit clear. What you trying to implement is not clear.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala oops. It isn't, sorry. Still not clear though

Comment: Read about the modulo operator.

Answer (score 1):

This could be done more compactly by changing the if-tree in the loop to be just

```
if ((i % 4) == 0)
    printf("%d", c[i/4]);
```

or you could print every byte by doing something like

```
printf("%d", (c[i/4] >> (i%4 * 8)) & 0xff);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `#define C_LEN 3` and use that instead of your magic number 3. You loop prints out a '|' in every iteration so your loop body cannot really be simplified other than:

```
if(!(i % 4)) printf("%d", c[i/4]);
```

If you only want to print something for 0, 4 and 8 then you iterate by 4 instead of 1, or better iterate by 1 (see below).

The output is:

```
| 3| | | | 1| | | | 2| | |
```

If that is all you want, I would write a single print statement:

```
printf("| %d| | | | %d| | | | %d| | | ", c[0], c[1], c[2]);
```

Or if you want a loop on group at a time and just iterate to 3 times:

```
for (int i = 0; i < C_LEN; i++) {
  printf("| %d| | | ", c[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are trying to print the elements of the array, based on multiple of 4.

You can generalize your program by creating an array of any size and have your `for` loop like this:

```
int index = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < lange*4; i++) 
{
    printf("| ");
    if (i == 0) 
    {
        index = 0;
    }
    else if((i % 4) == 0) 
    {
        index = i/4;
    }
    else 
    {
        continue;
    }
    
    printf("%d",c[index]);
}
```